# How to fit a gradual upward curve

Tags: regression, curve-fitting

I'm trying to fit a curve to my data (shown below), but I'm not sure of the best way to do it. I tried an exponential function following [this tutorial](https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/r-tutorial-5), but it didn't fit the data at all (just a vertical line), and now a square root function ( y~x+sqrt(x) ), which seems to fit the data well but curves upwards near the y axis, which is unrealistic. It is an understatement to say mathematics is not a strong point for me, and I'm struggling to find the right option. How can I make a line that only curves upwards, but does so gradually?

[image: plot with upward curve]

Comment: This looks very exponential. I wonder if you made a mistake in your code/fit process.

Comment: Please, joint to your question the numerical data (instead of graphical). One cannot reproduce what you did without data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you already tried y = a + bx + cx^2? You will need to use regression software to find the values of a, b, and c (which your software will probably call betas 0, 1, and 2)

Comment: Thanks, that's done it. I had used a squared term before and the curve went the other direction (correctly) - I had thought that to get the opposite direction I needed to use the opposite function... Now I realise it's just to do with the positive/negative coefficients *facepalm*